# How can I add totals from a file in a dos batch

Tags: windows-xp, batch-file

I want to add totals from lines in a text file.

My **file.txt** looks like this:

```
Totals: 7 passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
Totals: 10 passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
Totals: 6 passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
Totals: 9 passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
Totals: 4 passed, 0 failed, 1 skipped
Totals: 31 passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
Totals: 10 passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
Totals: 4 passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
Totals: 8 passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped
```

So when I run `sumtotals.bat file.txt` then I want something like this:

```
Passed : XX
Failed : 0
Skipped: X
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can to this:

```
@echo off

set passed=0
set failed=0
set skipped=0

for /f "tokens=2,4,6 delims= " %%a in (%1) do call :add %%a %%b %%c

echo passed=%passed%
echo failed=%failed%
echo skipped=%skipped%


goto :eof


:add
REM echo %1 %2 %3
set /a passed=%passed%+%1
set /a failed=%failed%+%2
set /a skipped=%skipped%+%3


:eof
```

result:

```
C:\temp>sumtotals.bat file.txt
passed=89
failed=0
skipped=1
```

Comment: +1, if you use `set /a passed+= ...` and so on, then you didn't need the (slow) call.